# Masked redirect to another folder over root

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, virtualhost

I have domain `www.domain.com`, and there are images in `www.domain.com/data/photos/*.*`. What I want, is access this images (with Virtual Host and masked - ie. I dont want the url to be changed, I want to have virtual subdomain url) as this url `http://img.domain.com/*.*`

My major website is on `/data/web/domain.com/web/*.*`.

Subdomains can be created in `/data/web/domain.com/sub/*.*`.

I tried this, but its not working:

```
DocumentRoot /data/web/domain.com/sub
ServerName domain.com
ServerAlias img.domain.com
Alias /img /data/web/domain.com/web/data/photos
```

Also tried about 5 solutions here on SO, but none worked for me. 
Where is the problem?

**EDITED:**

This is my current settings of Virtual Host:

```
DocumentRoot /data/web/domain.com/web
ServerName www.domain.com
ServerAlias domain.com
ServerAlias img.domain.com
```

And I tried to add this to `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^img.domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/data/photos/$1 [R,L]
```

It is working, but it is changing the url, when I enter f.e `http://img.domain.com/image.jpg` it is changed in the browser to `http://www.domain.com/data/photos/image.jpg`.

In short; I want when you type `http://img.domain.com/image.jpg` to show the content of file located in `/data/web/domain.com/web/data/photos/image.jpg`.

How to prevent this change of URL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
RewriteRule "/(.*)\.(jpg|gif|png)$" "http://img.domain.com/$1.$2" [P]
```

Instead of:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^img.domain.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain.com/data/photos/$1 [R,L]
```

According to [apache RewriteRule documentation](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html)

Note: **mod_proxy** must be enabled in order to use this flag.

**EDITED**

I have found a solution!
Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_FINISH} !^$
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^img.domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /data/photos/$1 [L,E=FINISH:1]
```

The first two rows help you to prevent infinite loop.

Comment: This will do something really different. Also I dont want to use mod_proxy, I am on the same domain. I want when you type `http://img.domain.com/image.jpg` to show the content of file located in `/data/web/domain.com/web/data/photos/image.jpg`.

Comment: I have updated my post, hope this would help you. Sorry for my first useless answer.

Comment: Of course I tried removing `R`, but it wont help. It will do nothing then.

Comment: I have found it! Please, check my updated post. Hope this time I will help you.

Comment: so, what about my updated solution? I have tested it, it returns something from /data/photos/ without redirecting.

Comment: I changed it, its working also without `,E=FINISH:1`.